# Sollten Fragen nach dem Namen von Stilmitteln erlaubt sein?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, allowed-questions

Heute frisch neu ist die folgende Frage:

**[What is the stylistic device in *Pistolenstich und Messerschuss*?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/30019/15318)**

Offensichtlich versteht der Fragesteller die deutschen Wörter und deren Bedeutung, erkennt, dass hier ein Stilmittel vorliegt (Vertauschung der Wortteile) und möchte wissen, wie das heißt. Ich glaube, dass hier ein kleines Dilemma vorliegt:

- Einerseits behandelt die Frage etwas, das mit Sprache zu tun hat, nämlich ein Stilmittel, das ohne Sprache nicht existieren kann.
- Andererseits denke ich, dass Stilmittel mehr oder weniger in vielen wenn nicht allen Sprachen gleichermaßen angewendet werden können, und die entsprechenden griechischen oder lateinischen Namen überall äquivalent sind.
- Dritterseits gibt es sicherlich papierne oder internetbasierte Stilmittelverzeichnisse, in denen sich eine solche Antwort schnell nachschlagen lassen müsste.
- Vierterseits sind die Stilmittel (zu meinem damaligen Leidwesen) Bestandteil des Deutschunterrichtes; dass man hier landet, um die Frage zu stellen, erscheint klar.

Wie wollen wir also mit Fragen nach den Namen von Stilmitteln umgehen? Schließen, beantworten oder offenlassen?

Eine kurze Suche durch Meta ergibt keine vergleichbare Diskussion.

Comment: Ein ähnlicher Präzedenzfall ist die Frage [Name der stilistischen Figur »ruhe sanfte, sanfte ruh!«](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/18084/9551). Vergleichbar ist vielleicht auch die Frage [Wie nennt man eine Wortveredelung durch Komposition?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3892/9551).

Comment: Möglicherweise ist der o.a. Fall ein *spezifisch auf die deutsche Sprache bezogener* - Weil es in der Frage um zusammengesetzte Substantive geht, die es so vorzugsweise im Deutschen gibt. Damit fällt mMn "...können in vielen, wenn nicht allen Sprachen..." für diese spezifische Frage schonmal weg.

Comment: @tofro *Cut of a pistol, shot of a knife* … nein.

Comment: @Jan Ich befürchte, das ist ähnlich, aber nicht dasselbe - Gebe aber zu, dass ich die Frage gerne beantwortet sähe, weil's mich interessiert...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zumindest, wenn nach dem deutschen Namen eines Stilmittels gefragt wird, sollten die Fragen meines Erachtens offen bleiben, und zwar aus einem ganz anderen Grund als den bisher genannten, nämlich als [single-word-request](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request). Es handelt sich um Fragen, die einen deutschen Begriff suchen, der zu einer bestimmten Bedeutung passt, und es ist plausibel, dass ein solcher Begriff existiert.

Ob der gesuchte Begriff selbst einen Bezug zur deutschen Sprache im Sinne unserer Seite hat, ist also gar nicht wichtig. Selbst die Frage nach dem deutschen Namen eines Stilmittels, das in der deutschen Sprache nicht anwendbar ist, wäre on-topic.

> Dritterseits gibt es sicherlich papierne oder internetbasierte Stilmittelverzeichnisse, in denen sich eine solche Antwort schnell nachschlagen lassen müsste.

Mit dem Argument dürften wir fast gar keine Fragen mehr zulassen. Die [Liste rhetorischer Stilmittel der Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_rhetorischer_Stilmittel) ist in etwa viertausend Wörter lang – wie auch der Abschnitt über das Komma in den offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln. Beide sind ähnlich leicht oder schwer zu verdauen. Erstere ist vermutlich unvollständig.

Answer (score 11):

Fragen nach Stilmitteln sind erlaubt, da sie integraler Bestandteil der Sprachverwendung sind. Auch Fragen nach dem Namen von Stilmitteln sind demnach erlaubt, weil diese Teil des Stilmittels sind und nicht trivial ersichtlich ist, ob sie, die Namen, aus anderen Sprachen übertragen werden können.

Stilmittelverzeichnisse sind darüber hinaus keine Art von Nachschlagewerk, die ein durchschnittlicher Sprachnutzer erwartungsgemäß kennen oder verfügbar haben muss.

Answer (score 2):

Ich gehe auch davon aus, dass wir diese Fragen, selbst wenn sie nicht beantortet werden, zumindest zur Zeit offen lassen sollten. Speziell wenn Erklärungen zur Herkunft und Verwendung gewünscht werden, halte ich diese für nicht off-topic.

Comment: Es kann ja sein, dass es gar keinen eigenen Begriff gibt. Dass es keinen gibt, oder dass unter den vielen Nutzern hier keiner geläufig ist, ist ja auch eine interessante Information.

Answer (score 0):

> Andererseits denke ich, dass Stilmittel mehr oder weniger in vielen wenn nicht allen Sprachen gleichermaßen angewendet werden können, und die entsprechenden griechischen oder lateinischen Namen überall äquivalent sind.

Das ist keineswegs der Fall. Beispielsweise ist der *Schüttelreim* eine ausschließlich deutsche (möglicherweise auch ungarische,da bin ich mir nicht sicher) Sache, während der *Limerick* als Form ausschließlich im englischen Sprachraum als Erscheinung existiert.

Jetzt kann man darüber diskutieren, ob bestimmte Reimformen unter die "Stilmittel" zu zählen sind, so wie ich das gerade getan habe. Unbestreitbar aber hat jede Sprache ihre morphologischen Besonderheiten, die bestimmte Formen überhaupt erst erlauben oder verbieten.

Schüttelreime funktionieren im Deutschen meiner Vermutung nach deshalb (so gut), weil der deutsche Wortschatz im Vergleich zu anderen Sprachen enorm viele Komposita enthält (zB "Liebesreise" => "Leibesriese", "Hausmeister" => "Maus heißt er"). Ich könnte mir zB. auch vorstellen, daß es Sprachen gibt, deren Syntax etwa die Weglassung eines Satzteils nicht erlauben, sodaß *Ellipse* und *Zeugma* schon deshalb nicht möglich wären.

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass es deutsche Limericks gibt.