# Was ist eine "general reference"?

Tags: discussion

*Zunächst eine Warnung: der Autor bedient sich hin und wieder des Stilmittels des Sarkasmus, manchmal auch der reductio ad absurdum und anderer Stilmittel, die hier - siehe unten - nichts verloren haben. Auch hat er sich eine Neigung zum Spielen mit Sprache und - horribile dictu - Humor bewahrt.* **Das Lesen erfolgt also auf eigene Gefahr!**

In den Regeln steht, daß Fragen, die man durch Nachschlagen in "general references" beantworten kann, off-topic sind. Dazu, bzw. zu einer Diskussion darüber, kam es im Zuge meiner Antwort [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/beantworten-von-off-topic-fragen/1792?noredirect=1#comment4381_1792) (siehe die anschließende Diskussion mit @infinitezero).

Die Frage ist so einfach nicht zu beantworten, denn: ich gehe davon aus, daß die meisten hier keine eigenen und zur Zeit unpublizierten wissenschaftlichen Erkenntnisse in Sachen Linguistik, Morphologie, Grammatik, Etymologie und verwandten Gebieten aufzuweisen haben, folglich alles, was sie so von sich geben, irgendwo Erlerntes oder wenigstens Herausgefundenes und auch bereits Veröffentlichtes darstellt.

Nun, dieselben Quellen, derer sie sich bedient haben um das zu lernen, was sie wissen, stehen auch allen anderen offen! Mit anderen Worten: *richten wir einfach, statt in German.SE Fragen zu beantworten, die sowieso alle off-topic weil selber recherchierbar sind, eine statische Seite mit dem Inhalt*

> Das, was Du wissen willst, steht in einem Buch - finde es, lies es und Du hast die Antwort!

ein. Ich bin sicher, damit wäre der Welt unendlich geholfen und jeder der Fragen zur deutschen Sprache hat, würde immens davon profitieren.

Einige werden jetzt sicher einwenden, daß man doch genau wisse, was darunter zu verstehen ist: Wörterbücher und so ...

Das Problem liegt im "und so ...", ansonsten käme es nicht zu Fragen wie [dieser](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1122/sollten-fragen-nach-dem-namen-von-stilmitteln-erlaubt-sein?rq=1), die "und so ..." zumindest dahingehend erweitert wissen will:

> Dritterseits gibt es sicherlich papierne oder internetbasierte Stilmittelverzeichnisse, in denen sich eine solche Antwort schnell nachschlagen lassen müsste.

Aha, also "Wörterbücher, Stilmittelverzeichnisse und so ...". Kann man dann

> [Deutsche Morphologie](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110212617/html)

auch zu "und so ..." dazuzählen? DeGruyter bezeichnet es immerhin als "Lexikon". Das bedeutet: Fragen zur Morphologie sollten - möglichst ohne Verweis auf das Buch, die Leute sollen gefälligst selber recherchieren - einfach als off-topic geschlossen werden.

Syntax? Auch kein Problem: Noam Chomskys *Syntactic Structures* ("Strukturen der Syntax", DeGruyter Mouton, 1973) oder, wers etwas allgemeiner mag, schließlich ist Syntax ein Teilbereich der Semiotik: *Encyclopedic Dictionary of Semiotics* (Hrsg. Thomas Sebeok, 1986). Wir müssen uns also nicht weiter mit Fragen zur Syntax aufhalten.

Die Frage lautet also: **was genau soll unter "general references" verstanden werden**?

Vielleicht auch noch, angeschlossen: **wieviel Recherche ist einem Fragesteller eigentlich zuzumuten**? Reicht eine Google-Suche? Master-Abschluß in Germanistik? Etwas dazwischen?

Comment: Aus der akzeptierten Antwort, aus der von dir verlinkten Frage: "Mit dem Argument dürften wir fast gar keine Fragen mehr zulassen. Die Liste rhetorischer Stilmittel der Wikipedia ist in etwa viertausend Wörter lang – wie auch der Abschnitt über das Komma in den offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln. Beide sind ähnlich leicht oder schwer zu verdauen. Erstere ist vermutlich unvollständig." Damit scheint ein Stilmittelverzeichnis nicht dazuzuzählen.

Comment: Kannst du ein Beispiel angeben, in dem eine Frage deiner Meinung nach "unrechtmäßig" geschlossen wurde? Mir ist aus diesem Post noch nicht ganz ersichtlich, warum genau das ein Problem ist / wann es zu einem Problem wird.

Comment: Ungeachtet dessen, kann ich eine general reference (wie speziell du das auch immer auslegen möchtest), auch einfach nicht verstanden werden. Von daher ist es umso wichtiger, dass Leute dazu schreiben, was ihr Kenntnis stand ist. Je genauer sie ihr Problem erläutern, desto besser kann ihnen geholfen werden. Verglichen mit anderen SE sieht man das recht oft (z.B. Math und Physics). Dort sind z.B. aber Hausaufgaben fragen nur bedingt erlaubt. Jedenfalls nicht in "macht meine Arbeit für mich".

Comment: @infinitezero: nein, ich kann kein Beispiel angeben, weil es mir überhaupt nicht darum ging. Das hat nur guidot in seiner Antwort (zu Unrecht) vermutet. Was genau meiner Frage(n) war(en), ist nachzulesen - ohne Hintergedanken. Ich denke mir halt, ein Satz wie "Alle pfrmtl sollen zwcksy sein." kann auch erst beurteilt werden, wenn man weiß, was "pfrmtl" und "zwcksy" überhaupt sein sollen. Danach kann entscheiden, ob das auch wirklich so sein muß, aber davor ist das nur leeres, nichtssagendes Gerede.

Comment: Dein Vergleich hinkt. [General Reference](https://web.library.yale.edu/collection-development/general-reference-collection) ist kein so obskurer Begriff, wie du ihn auszumachen scheinst. Speziell: Alles was irgendwo irgendwie mal veröffentlicht wurde zählt nicht einfach deswegen direkt als General Reference.

Comment: @infinitezero: Ich habe nicht behauptet (und werde es auch nicht tun),, daß "general reference" ein obskurer Begriff sei.Ich habe lediglich zu erläutern versucht, warum ich es für eine gute Idee halte, sich darüber auszutauschen, was *wir hier für unsere Zwecke* als "general reference* versatnden wissen wollen. Konkret: sollen zB Stilmittelverzeichnisse dazugehören oder nicht? Und bevor Du darauf eingehst: mir ist schon klar, daß Stilmittelverzeichnisse eher nicht dazugehören (sollen), aber für anderes, was durchaus unter "general reference" fällt, ist die Sache nicht so klar.

Comment: Darum hast Du ja auch - und das finde ich eine gute Idee - begonnen, eine Liste mit Links/Publikationen anzulegen. Die kann nicht nur als Leitlinie für uns selbst, sondern auch als "Liste zu verwendender Nachschlageorte" für Fragesteller hilfreich sein.

Answer (score 2):

## Übersetzungen / Translations

https://www.dict.cc/
https://www.deepl.com/translator
https://translate.google.com/
https://dict.leo.org/

## Definitionen / Definitions

https://www.duden.de/
https://www.dwds.de/
https://de.wikipedia.org/

## Etymologie / Etymology

https://www.dwds.de/
https://www.wiktionary.org/

## Flexion / Inflection

https://www.wiktionary.org/

## Zeichensetzung / Punctuation

http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Aus der Frage lese ich die Hypothese heraus, hier würden zu viele Fragen geschlossen, speziell mit dem Grund "kann nachgeschlagen werden" unter Verweis auf möglicherweise schwer zugängliche Fachliteratur.

Ich sehe das nicht. Die Quote für das Schließen von Fragen insgesamt beträgt <13%, davon wiederum 22% mit dem besagten Grund, was auf ca. 3% aller Fragen hinausläuft. Ich habe nicht wahrgenommen, dass davon ein signifikanter Anteil kontrovers ist.

Das Grundproblem scheint mir eher zu sein, dass sich einige Fragende mit dem Sichten des ersten Suchmaschinen-Treffers oder gar noch weniger begnügen, bevor sie ihr Thema als fragenswert betrachten, oft auch keine weiteren hier gestellten Fragen mit den relevanten Tags heranziehen.

Wenn Duden oder DWDS, vielleicht noch eine Grammatik und die amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln die Frage nicht beantworten, sehe ich keinen Anlass, eine Frage deswegen zu schließen.

Die Stoßrichtung in der verlinkten Diskussion schien mir auch eher zu sein, dass wir mit dem zügigen Schließen der x-ten Frage mit dem gleichen Kernproblem zu verhindern versuchen, noch zahllose weitere äquivalente Fragen ("mit einem anderen Adjektiv") zu ernten.

---

Update: Ich mag gedruckte Referenzwerke auch gerne, aber es sprechen dagegen:

- man benötigt statt eines Links eine Quellenangabe, die sehr viel schwieriger zu erstellen, zu verifizieren und auszuwerten ist
- Fragende aus dem Ausland sind bezüglich deren Zugänglichkeit im Hintertreffen
- Die Kostenfrage stellt sich für Gedrucktes und ebenso für kostenpflichtige Portale

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, woraus Du das "herausliest", denn hineingeschrieben habe ich es nicht. Offensichtlich sind aber - und das habe ich sehr wohl geschrieben - Stilmittelverzeichnisse wohl ebenso unter "general references" einzureihen, wenigstens nach der Meinung dessen, der das so geschrieben hat. Und warum gerade DWDS, warum nicht den Wahrig, den Grimm oder irgendein anderes Wörterbuch? Den Begriff "Prägarbe" habe ich zB im DWDS nicht gefunden, also sollte man vielleicht ein Lexikon der Mathematik auch dazunehmen (so wie ein paar hundert andere Fachwörterbücher). Langsam wird die Liste lang...

Comment: @bakunin meiner Meinung nach reicht es, wenn man zeigt, dass man sich Mühe gegeben hat. Eine Frage zu stellen wie, "Was versteht man unter Prägarbe" ich habe den Begriff nicht in DWDS finden können, ist vollkommen in Ordnung. Man muss nicht alle general References durchsehen. Wie guidot schon geschrieben hat: **Das Grundproblem scheint mir eher zu sein, dass sich einige Fragende mit dem Sichten des ersten Suchmaschinen-Treffers oder gar noch weniger begnügen, bevor sie ihr Thema als fragenswert betrachten**.

Comment: @infinitezero: Das kann man durchaus so sehen, aber dann sollte eben *das* als Regel gelten und nicht "schau halt die general references durch". Andererseits habe ich diese Frage (https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71047/regeln-f%c3%bcr-das-geschlecht-von-indefinita-bzw-indefiniten-nominalphrasen) gestellt ohne den Duden vorher zu konsultieren, denn dort hat sich ja die Lösung gefunden. Für mich ist ein wichtiger Aspekt dieses Threads halt auch, übereinzukommen bzw. sich darüber auszutauschen, was wir als Community als "ausreichend" betrachten.

Comment: "If your question could be answered by a dictionary, thesaurus, or another general reference, consult these. **Explain why this did not help you when asking your question.**" Du schriebst: "An einschlägigem Material habe ich lediglich Genuswechsel in Kopulasätzen (PDF) gefunden, das aber das Thema auch nicht erschöpfend behandelt." Ich sehe da keinen Widerspruch. Du hast in eine Referenz geschaut und erklärt warum es nicht half. Es wird nicht verlangt, dass du ALLE Werke liest, lediglich dass du in eins schaust.

Comment: @infinitezero: Wenn nicht verlangt wird, daß man *alle* Werke liest, sondern lediglich, daß man in eins (irgendeins?) hineinschaut, dann erlaubst Du damit Fragen wie "Was ist die Bedeutung von 'Mama' und 'Papa', ich habe im 'Handwörterbuch für Brieftaubenzüchtung' nachgeschlagen und nichts gefunden." Du wirst sicher zugestehen, daß manche "general references" mehr "general" als andere sind. Stellt sich also die Frage, ob das nicht trotzdem zu schließen gewesen wäre, weil ich eben *nicht* im Duden fündig wurde, sondern nur irgendein obskures Paper (erfolglos) gelesen habe.

Comment: Ich verstehe dein Argument nicht. "Irgendein obskures Paper" ist offensichtlich per Definition keine General Reference. Ich verlange aber (generell), dass man den gesunden Menschenverstand nutzt (auch wenn der im Internet immer seltener wird). Das Handwörterbuch für Brieftaubenzüchtung Worte scheint mir nicht das nächstliegendste Buch zu sein. Du bist gerne eingeladen die Community Wiki hier zu erweitern, mit Werken die du als allgemeine Referenz für tauglich hälst.